# Move data in an array will overwrite data?

Tags: c, memcpy

I have a question regarding memcpy. I have a buffer and want to move data from the rear end of the buffer to the front. Something like this:

```
int buffer[100];
memcpy(buffer, buffer + 10, 30);
```

There is overlapping data (Elements 11 - 21), will there be data lost or will this copy the data to the front? Is this a "good practice"?

The background: I have a big buffer on a microcontroller and do not want to reallocate this buffer. Its a fifo buffer and everytime something gets read the data behind will be moved to the front. I do this to avoid memory fragmentation on the microcontroller.

Comment: use `memmove` when the buffers overlap

Comment: BTW, such a question is usually resolved *much faster* by looking at `man memcpy`.

Comment: The [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) for `memcpy` states very clearly: *The `memcpy()` function copies `n` bytes from memory area `src` to memory area `dest`. **The memory areas must not overlap.** Use `memmove(3)` if the memory areas do overlap.* That's actually the complete description given for the function.

Comment: In terms of speed, the "everytime something gets read the data behind will be moved to the front." sounds like that is the true performance issue.  It certainly sounds like the wrong design choice.  I suggest re-examining the design, rather than concerns about micro-optimization of `memcpy()`,  `memmove()`, vs. crafted code.

Comment: Speed does not matter that much in my case

Answer (score 2):

The manual for `memcpy` explicitly states that it is not to be used when the buffers overlap and that in such case you should use `memmove`:

> The memcpy() function copies n bytes from memory area src to memory area dest.  The memory areas must not overlap.  Use memmove(3) if the memory areas do overlap.

For completion's sake, here's the description of `memmove`:

> The  memmove() function copies n bytes from memory area src to memory area dest.  The memory areas may overlap: copying takes place as though the bytes in src are first copied into a temporary array that does not overlap src
>          or dest, and the bytes are then copied from the temporary array to dest.

Comment: Wont that cause the memory fragmentation?

Comment: No, there's just a temporary buffer used to prevent overwriting data that has yet to be copied.  The memory still gets copied to the same place in the end.

Comment: yes, but I work on a Controller with 2k of ram. What happens e.g. if my buffer is 128bytes and no temp array with 128 bytes can be allocated as temporary array? Would it not be better in this case to write a function that will copy bytewise in the overlapping area?

Comment: hmm, that may come down to implementation.  I would think it best to assume `memmove` is the way to go until proven otherwise.  Perhaps look into the implementation of `memmove` on your platform to get a better idea.

Comment: according to a post in a arduino forum its better to copy bytes by hand because the memmove overhead is rather expensive... Thats why I hoped memcpy will work...

Comment: How costly is the fragmentation of wrapping at the end of the buffer vs. constantly rearranging the buffer so that it's completely sequential?

Comment: if the memory is too fragmented and the temp array does not fit it might come to a stack and heap clash...

Comment: I am trying to understand the fragmentation issue you are worried about.  I'm not sure I follow your concern.  With a circular buffer/queue where data wraps back to the beginning when it reaches the end, I don't think that should be an issue of fit anymore than the you'd get from rearranging the buffer every time you remove something from the beginning.  But that discussion might be best for a question about preventing fragmentation rather than a question about copying memory in overlapping buffers.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a "good practice"?

It's undefined behavior, so don't do it.

Use [`memmove()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html) which is designed specifically for this.

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The *memmove()* function copies n bytes from memory area src to memory
>      area dest.  The memory areas may overlap: copying takes place as
>      though the bytes in src are first copied into a temporary array that
>      does not overlap src or dest, and the bytes are then copied from the
>      temporary array to dest.

The following paragraph, taken from [memcpy()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html)'s manual page clearly states that both POSIX and the C standard *are explicit* in that it's udnefined behavior to use `memcpy()` with overlapping areas.

> **NOTES**
>
> Failure to observe the requirement that the memory areas do not
>      overlap has been the source of significant bugs. (**POSIX and the C
>      standards are explicit that employing *memcpy()* with overlapping areas
>      produces undefined behavior.**)  Most notably, in glibc 2.13 a
>      performance optimization of *memcpy()* on some platforms (including
>      x86-64) included changing the order in which bytes were copied from
>      src to dest.

Answer (score 1):

`memcpy` is the wrong function for this task:

> *man memcpy*, *man memmove*
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
>
> void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
> void *memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
> ```
>
> The  `memcpy()`  function copies `n` bytes from memory area `src` to memory area `dest`.
>   **The memory areas must not overlap**.  Use `memmove(3)` if the memory areas do overlap.
>
> The  `memmove()` function copies `n` bytes from memory area `src` to memory area `dest`.
>   **The memory areas may overlap**: copying takes place as though the bytes in `src` are
>   first copied into a temporary array that does not overlap `src` or `dest`, and the bytes
>   are then  copied  from the temporary array to `dest`.